# Android edittext cannot enter to next edittext

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I have 3 edittext in my activity. The first edittext will be setFocusable(false) if the edittext length is not equal to 0(value on 1st edittext will be from sqlite). So when I start the activity, the focus will be on the second edittext. If I click on the 1st edittext, a dialog will prompt with YES and NO button. If I click yes, it will focus on the 1st edittext and I can edit the value. But when I press the enter key on the phone keyboard, it will not direct me to the second edittext. It will stay on the 1st edittext. The only way I can go to the second edittext is to press the back button and click on the 2nd edittext. Any idea how can I fix this problem?

Here's my code for the edittext:

```
if (txtBudgetText.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
        txtBudgetText.setFocusable(false);
        this.txtBudgetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBudget);
        this.txtBudgetText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // custom dialog
                if ((txtBudgetText.getText().toString().length() != 0) && (txtBudgetText.isFocused()==false) ) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.edit_budget);
                    dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");

                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and
                    // button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.text);
                    text.setText("Are you sure you want to edit your budget?");
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.image);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.warning);

                    Button dialogYESButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonYes);
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogYESButton
                            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    EditText txtBudgetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBudget);
                                    txtBudgetText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                                    txtBudgetText.setFocusable(true);
                                    txtBudgetText.requestFocus();
                                    //txtBudgetText.setText("");
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                    Button dialogNOButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonNo);
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogNOButton
                            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `txtBudgetText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo. IME_ACTION_NEXT);` after you called `findViewById` or set it in your layout.xml by setting `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in your EditText layout declaration.

Comment: Great, that's what it's supposed to do. Keep in mind that accepting answers also increases your personal reputation on Stackoverflow. ;-)

Comment: I will accept the answer soon because stackoverflow only allow me to accept after 6 minute

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            if (e1.getText().toString().length() == 1) // size as per your
                                                        // requirement
            {
                e2.requestFocus();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you add a few lines to explain your solution ? Thanks.